Self made vehicles game show
I'm looking for the name of an old TV game show (1980s/1990s) where contestants must race along an above water track in self made vehicles, winners must reach and ring a bell at the end of the track.
Presenters speak Dutch so I think the show is either from the Netherlands or from Belgium. 

why the down votes ?

This is Te land, ter zee, en in de lucht, which translates as "on land, at sea and in the air". It's a Dutch TV show, broadcast by the TROS since 1971. Since 2010, it's co-produced with VTM.
Contestants compete in home-built vehicles. They have to complete a course, which differs from episode to episode. It usually involves the risk of getting wet, like "Hoog en Droog" ("high and dry") where contestants must cross a canal on two steel wires, "Fiets 'm d'r In" ("bike 'em in") where they must navigate a narrow runway above water, or "Tobbedansen" ("tub dancing") where they must go down a ramp, into or rather across the water to ring a bell.
Almost always the contestant must ring a bell to have their time recorded.
Winter episodes are shot in the Alps, where contestants must go down a mountain.
The show used to contain motor sports challenges as well, like racing backwards or racing with a caravan in tow (at least the hitch and the wheels of the caravan needed to make it across the finish line).
Episodes can be watched online, through the TROS's website.
